# Highcharts Marimekko chart refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The script below builds a basic Marimekko chart where the x-values are cumulative. This is awesome as an exciting way to plot data. http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/1o926coh/

Unfortunately, when you toggle areas in the legend, the script simply 'hides' the areas concerned, meaning that there are gaps in the chart. How could I amend this script so the "allSeries" array is recalculated each time a button in the legend is toggled?

To repeat and hopefully clarify what I'm after: tHe idea is that if I remove the green area, then the black and orange series should be adjacent.

```
$(function () {
    var rawData = [
        { name: 'A', x: 5, y: 5.6 },
        { name: 'B', x: 3, y: 10.1 },
        { name: 'C', x: 11, y: 1.2 },
        { name: 'D', x: 2, y: 17.8 },
        { name: 'E', x: 8, y: 8.4 }
    ];

function makeSeries(listOfData) {
    var sumX = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfData.length; i++) {
        sumX += listOfData[i].x;
    }
    var allSeries = []
    var x = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfData.length; i++) {
        var data = listOfData[i];
        allSeries[i] = {
            name: data.name,
            data: [
                [x, 0], [x, data.y],
                {
                    x: x + data.x / 2.0,
                    y: data.y,
                    dataLabels: { enabled: false, format: data.x + ' x {y}' }
                },
                [x + data.x, data.y], [x + data.x, 0]
            ],
            w: data.x,
            h: data.y
        };
        x += data.x + 0;
    }
    return allSeries;
}

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: { type: 'area' },
    xAxis: {
        tickLength: 0,
        labels: { enabled: true}
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: { enabled: false}
    },
    plotOptions: {

        area: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: { enabled: false }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: makeSeries(rawData)
});
```

});

Let me know your thoughts!

Original script: [How can I change the width of the bars in a highchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058195/how-can-i-change-the-width-of-the-bars-in-a-highchart)

Comment: You can use [`legendItemClick`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) event, where you can update all series according to new calculations. To update series' points, use simple `chart.series[index].setData(new_data)`.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing :-) Thanks Pawel, good to know I am on the right track. The tricky bit is to rebuild the array (I am a bit of an array rook)

Comment: Quick question: how do I return the ID of the series clicked? i.e. the first one would be [0], the second [1] and so on...

Comment: .... and I found it. `this.index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you again Pawel, that is indeed the answer to the question.

A possible solution looks a bit like this:

```
legendItemClick: function () {
                    var pos = this.index;
                    var sname = this.name;
                    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                    while(chart.series.length > 0)
                    chart.series[0].remove(true);
                    rawData[pos]= { name: sname, x: 0, y: 0 };        
                    ... then update the series with the new array  
                              }
```