# Restacking cumulative columns in Highcharts marimekko charts

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, highcharts, marimekko-chart

I've got a basic variable width column chart (aka Marimekko) set up using Highcharts but am having trouble getting it to restack the columns properly to eliminate the data gap once a series has been removed or hidden.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akaimo/9663eufs/7/) <-- I've set up a demo of the issue here.

You'll notice clicking on a legend item removes the series from the chart, but it also removes all of the following data points in the array (i.e. clicking on series **C** removes series **C**, **D**, and **E** whereas it should redraw to **A-B-D-E**). Since the y-axis data is meant to display a cumulative sum of all series, these should re-shuffle as adjacent columns with no gaps.  How can I get this to render properly?

[THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692037/highcharts-marimekko-chart-refresh) uses similar demo code and attempting to solve the same problem, however the answer is somewhat elusive and I am unable to get it working.

Thanks in advance!

```
$(function () {
var dataArray = [
    { name: 'A', x: 200, y: 120 },
    { name: 'B', x: 380, y: 101 },
    { name: 'C', x: 450, y: 84 },
    { name: 'D', x: 198, y: 75 },
    { name: 'E', x: 95, y: 55 }
];

function makeSeries(listOfData) {
    var sumX = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfData.length; i++) {
        sumX += listOfData[i].x;
    }
    var allSeries = []
    var x = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfData.length; i++) {
        var data = listOfData[i];
        allSeries[i] = {
            name: data.name,
            data: [
                [x, 0], [x, data.y],
                {
                    x: x + data.x / 2.0,
                    y: data.y,
                    dataLabels: { enabled: false, format: data.x + ' x {y}' }
                },
                [x + data.x, data.y], [x + data.x, 0]
            ],
            w: data.x,
            h: data.y
        };
        x += data.x + 0;
    }
    return allSeries;
}

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: { type: 'area' },
    xAxis: {
        tickLength: 0,
        labels: { enabled: true}
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: { enabled: false}
    },
    plotOptions: {
         series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    var pos = this.index;
                    var sname = this.name;
                    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                    while(chart.series.length > 0) {
                        chart.series[pos].remove(true);
                    }
                    dataArray[pos]= { name: sname, x: 0, y: 0 };
                    chart.series[0].setData(dataArray);
                }
            }
        },
        area: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: { enabled: false }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: makeSeries(dataArray)
});
```

});

Comment: It removes because you iterate on each serie and destroy it. So why you not leave deafault action? http://jsfiddle.net/9663eufs/8/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian.  Yes I can have this eliminate the clicked series without iterating though the data but it would still leave a gap in the x-axis.

Comment: But in my example it works, so Im confused a little bit.

Comment: It looks like it works if you remove each series starting from the right (E-D-C - etc.), however if you click to hide a series that is not on the end it produces a gap in the x-axis continuity.  I am trying to have the columns shift left so that the last x-axis value is the sum of all the visible column x-axis values.