# Chartkick column chart: change column width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I really couldn't find any documentation about this simple question:

***How to change the column width in a Chartkick column chart in RoR?***

The aim is to avoid the case in the image below, where the column is too thick in case of a one-column chart

[image: Too fat column]

In the [documentation](https://www.chartkick.com/) it mentions Highchart, so I tried putting some hash parameters according to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058195/how-can-i-change-the-width-of-the-bars-in-a-highchart), like this:

```
<%= column_chart(
  @data,
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointWidth: 15
    }
  }
  )
%>
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts options need to be nested inside the `library` option:

```
<%= column_chart @data, library: {plotOptions: {series: {pointWidth: 15}}} %>
```